# error in auto-correction function: string 2 list

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to auto-correct words in extracted tweets. I checked the text type. 
<>

but the error says "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'"
i.e it's a list object ....how do i resolve this.

I am pretty new with python... please help me with the error.

```
text=remove_punctuation(clean_emoji(remove_rt(strip_links(tweet.text))))
print(type(text)) 

#SOURCE_CODE: https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

def words(text): return re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())
WORDS = Counter(words(open('C:/Users/Paromita/Desktop/Travel Recommendation/big.txt').read()))     #count all the words in "big.txt" document
                                                                                                   #import Counter
def P(word, N=sum(WORDS.values())):                                                                #provides probability of the word
    return WORDS[word] / N

def known(words):                                                                                  #The subset of `words` that appear in the dictionary of WORDS.
    return set(w for w in words if w in WORDS)

def edits1(word):                                                                                  #All edits that are one edit away from `word`
    letters    = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    splits     = [(word[:i], word[i:])    for i in range(len(word) + 1)]
    deletes    = [L + R[1:]               for L, R in splits if R]
    transposes = [L + R[1] + R[0] + R[2:] for L, R in splits if len(R)>1]
    replaces   = [L + c + R[1:]           for L, R in splits if R for c in letters]
    inserts    = [L + c + R               for L, R in splits for c in letters]
    return set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts)

def edits2(word):                                                                                  #All edits that are two edits away from `word`
    return (e2 for e1 in edits1(word) for e2 in edits1(e1))

def candidates(word):                                                                              #Generate possible spelling corrections for word.
    return (known([word]) or known(edits1(word)) or known(edits2(word)) or [word])

def correction(word):                                                                              #  Most probable spelling correction for word
    return max(candidates(word), key=P)

def autocorrect(word):
    for w in words(text):
        word=word.replace(w,correction(w))
    return word
```

Error:

```
<ipython-input-124-2d46c58aaf5d> in autocorrect(word)
     29 
     30 def autocorrect(word):
---> 31     for w in words(text):
     32         word=word.replace(w,correction(w))
     33     return word

<ipython-input-124-2d46c58aaf5d> in words(text)
      1 #SOURCE_CODE: https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html
      2 
----> 3 def words(text): return re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())
      4 WORDS = Counter(words(open('C:/Users/Paromita/Desktop/Travel Recommendation/big.txt').read()))     #count all the words in "big.txt" document
      5                                                                                                    #import Counter

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: Add relevant code... and as error says you are using `replace` on `list`instead of `str`

Comment: ḧow should anyone be able to help you if do do not post the source code that prooduces the error? please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `text` is a list of string.

**Try:**

```
def words(text):
    return re.findall(r'\w+', " ".join(text).lower())
```